# Why did '/Passenger.' break up?

Tags: history, bands

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_(British_band)) mentions that the British music band  */Passenger.* broke up in 2009 after releasing their debut and only album in 2007. I tried to find some other details but could not find much. Does anyone know the reasons behind the end of the band?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An article, in which Mike from the band is interviewed, says:
"We ended up releasing an album and touring, but for so many reasons it wasn't quite right. I think the potential was there, there was some great songs and I love those guys, they're still some of my best mates, but people were tugging in different directions and it ended up being a compromise. It was over thought and as a result it was wrong how it came out. It's quite a painful experience watching something that you are so passionate about come out pretty badly. But coming out of that I learnt so much, I learnt exactly what I didn't want to do and I learnt what was really important: great ideas, great songs, put over simply in an honest way."
https://brightonsfinest.com/html/index.php/spotlight/93-mike-rosenberg-interview-2014-03

On Rolling Stone's website there is an article saying: "About six years ago, Rosenberg and Andrew Phillips, a more experienced friend who specialized in film and soundtrack composing, formed Passenger. They wrote songs and toured, making what Rosenberg considered "a really great, raw and organic collaboration." But when they wound up putting out an album, 2007's Wicked Man's Rest, Rosenberg felt they compromised their vision in order to please other people. "I was a lot younger then and didn't have such a strong vision for what I wanted it to be," he says. "A lot of the eccentricity and what made it great had been kind of ironed out. As a result, it didn't really please anyone – it wasn't cool enough for the cool kids and it wasn't poppy enough for the pop kids."
http://www.rollingstone.com/music/news/passengers-long-road-to-overnight-success-20131220

And on HotPress, Mike said that Andrew leaving coincided with a relationship break up and his manager leaving too. It looks like everything just wound down as it as they didn't feel it was working- maybe too commercial and away from the roots they intended?
Mike has continued Passenger as a solo act and Andrew is a composer in TV and film.
Not a lot of detail seems to be out there, but I hope that helps.